# ASP.NET MVC input validation to allow only two digit numbers on a model property that is string type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

The input values can be any two digit numbers of the form `00, 01,...09,10,11,....19,20,...,99` etc. But following is not working. User can still enter `abc` and no client side validation occurs. Of course the error occurs after the form is posted since SQL Server does not except, for example,  `abc` in a char(2) column. It needs to occur during client side validation as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation). What I may be missing?

**Note**: Not using data type as number since it would force 01 to 1, 02 to 2 ,... etc. It has to be of the type 01, 02,  ...,etc.

**Model Snapshot**:

```
Column[TypeName = "char(2)"]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{2,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Must be two digits numbers"), StringLength(2)]
public string TestCode { get; set; }
```

**Views\Shared\Components\Default.cshtml**

```
 <form asp-controller="TestController" asp-action="TestAction" method="post">
       <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
       ....
       ....
       <div class="form-group">
           <label asp-for="TestCode" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
           <div class="col-md-2">
               <input asp-for="TestCode" class="form-control" />
               <span asp-validation-for="TestCode" class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>
       </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="TestVal">Save</button>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with latest update -3 and ASP.NET Core 1.1. The project is created using their default Web App Core template that includes built-in JQuery, JQuery-Validation, bootstrap etc. Following is the snapshot of the html generated in Google Chrome Dev Tool.

*Snapshot of Google Chrome Dev Tool*:

```
<label class="col-md-2 control-lable" for="TestCode">TestCode<label>
<div class="col-md-2">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" id="TestCode" name="TestCode" value>
   <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TestCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

When user clicks on Tab2 of the Main View (with Bootstrap Tabstrip), an Ajax code (shown below) displays a Partial view in Tab2 content pane that displays a list of various buttons. When user clicks on one of those buttons, same controller (shown below) calls a `ViewComponent` that displays the view in question (please see this ViewComponent view before `UPDATE` section above).

**Controller**:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult TestAction(string calledFrom, int SelectedOrderYear, int id)
{
    ....
    return ViewComponent("Test_VC", new { id = id });
}
```

**Main View with Bootstrap Tabs**:

```
@model MyProj.Models.TestViewModel
....
....
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li id="menu1ID" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li id="menu2ID"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">        
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
  </div>
</div>

@section scripts

$('#myTabstripID li').click(function () {
    var li_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("TestAction", "TestController")',
        data: { calledFrom: li_id },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (li_id == 'menu1ID')
                $('#menu1').html(data);
            else if (li_id == 'menu2ID')
                $('#menu2').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you included the relevant scripts for client side validation? And what is the actual html rendered by your `<input />` tag?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've just added and UPDATE section to answer your question.

Comment: There are no `data-val-*` attributes being generated  in the `<input />` Most common causes are you do not have this inside a `<form>` element, or you have previously generated another input for that property in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hmm!  I checked it's inside the form and it does successfully post the `TestCode` data to the SQL server where (as expected) SQL Server complains about entering longer string `abc` inside char(2) column. Moreover, all the input seem to have the form `<input class="form-control" type="..." id="..." name="..." value='...'>
` only - with no `data-val-*` attributes. Each input tag has unique property with `TestCode` not repeated anywhere. The view is generated via a partial view inside parent view. But that, I think, should not matter.

Comment: You will need to show more of your code (including the form tag  - is that in the partial or the main view? and are you using `@Html.Partial()` or loading it via ajax?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's a bit complicated but I've tried to add relevant parts in new **UPDATE 2** section with some explanation to answer your questions. The view in question is a `ViewComponent` (with a form tag included) that is called from controller after user clicks on a partial view button. Partial view is also called from controller.